# How does Variational AutoEncoder (VAE) get mean and variance?

Tags: machine-learning, entropy, neural-networks

Could somebody explain to me how VAE works in [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models.ipynb#scrollTo=1QxkfjtzE4X2) (look only at cell which starts with `class Sampling...`)?

`input=(batch_size=64, flatten_pixels=784)` goes to `Dense(64, 'relu')` layer. The result goes through `Dense(32)` twice in parallel. One output of it they call `z_mean`, another `z_log_var`. Why do they think that output of two identical `Dense(32)` layers with the same input should return mean and log variance? Reading about this topic I found that `z_mean` becomes a mean and `z_log_var` becomes a log variance during the loss minimization process.

Also, as far as I know:

```
KL Divergence = CrossEntropy - Entropy = -∑plog(q) - (-∑plog(p))
```

I know what KL Divergence is, I understand binary and cathegorical crossentropy, but I still can't understand why the loss calculated by the formula below forces one output of `Dense(32)` to be mean and another output to be log variance:

```
kl_loss = - 0.5 * tf.reduce_mean(
        z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var) + 1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318748/deriving-the-kl-divergence-loss-for-vaes) stats.se question.

Comment: anyone who is still looking for this answer, find it [here] (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353220/why-in-variational-auto-encoder-gaussian-variational-family-we-model-log-sig)

Answer (score 1):

The $n=1$ case of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/370048) obtains the KL loss as $-\frac12(1+\ln\sigma^2-\sigma^2-\mu^2)$. This is your formula with `z_mean` $\mu$ and `z_log_var` $\ln\sigma^2$.

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't understand. Can you explain why minimization of KL distance forces one output of `Dense(32)` to be mean and another output to be log variance